# MongoDB $switch aggregagation always falling in default case

Tags: mongodb

I have the following Mongo (simplified) aggregation :

```
db.getCollection('oees').aggregate([
{ $match: {"$or":[
        {"$and":[{"resId": ObjectId("568b9eb32847fe2000e0b071")},{"attachment":"turbine1"},{"date":{"$gte":ISODate("2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),"$lte":ISODate("2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}]}
        {"$and":[{"resId": ObjectId("...")},{"attachment":"..."},{"date":{"$gte":ISODate("..."),"$lte":ISODate("...")}}]}
]}}, { $group: {
      _id: { date: { $dateToString: { format: '‌%Y-%m', date: '$date' } }, resId: '$resId', attachment: '$attachment' },
    } },
    { $project: {
      _id: 1,
      resId: '$_id.resId',
      attachment: '$_id.attachment',
      date: '$_id.date',
      hoursCount: {'$switch':{'branches':[
        {'case':{'$eq':['$_id.date','2018-04']},'then':696},
        {'case':{'$eq':['$_id.date','2018-05']},'then':720},
        {'case':{'$eq':['$_id.date','2018-06']},'then':696}
      ], default:'$_id.date'}}
    } }
])
```

The aggregation queries the "oees" collection which is composed of documents like this one :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589cc8e894e30b006989627b"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "resId" : ObjectId("568b9eb32847fe2000e0b071"),
    "attachment" : "turbine1",
    "createAt" : ISODate("2017-02-09T19:54:13.537Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-02-09T19:54:13.537Z"),
    "indicator" : "availabilityLosses",
    "value" : 0,
    "unit" : "hours"
}
```

And it gives me, for example, the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "‌2018-06",
        "resId" : ObjectId("568b9eb32847fe2000e0b071"),
        "attachment" : "turbine1"
    },
    "resId" : ObjectId("568b9eb32847fe2000e0b071"),
    "attachment" : "turbine1",
    "date" : "‌2018-06",
    "hoursCount" : "‌2018-06",
}
```

But I can't understand why does `hoursCount` is equal to `2018-06` as this was one the cases of my `$switch`, which should have logically resolved to *696* ... but have resolved to the default case.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please share complete document

Comment: I updated the question with a sample document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. For an unknown reason, `$dateToString` is inserting an invisible character at the first position of the resulting string.

This undisplayable character is known as ‌‌**ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (U+200C)** and can be found in the General Punctuation block. It is represented with:

- ‌UTF-8 : 0xE2 0x80 0x8C
- UTF-16 : 0x200C
- Escaped octal C UTF-8 : \342\200\214
- Decimal XML entity : ‌

Answer (score 0):

> Change second and third step of aggregation.
>   Second step should be like this as mentioned below

```
    // Stage 2
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { 
            //  date: { $dateToString: { format: '‌%Y-%m', date: '$date' } }, 
              date: '$date', 
              resId: '$resId', attachment: '$attachment' 
              }
        }
    },
```

> Third step as mentioned below

```
{
        $project: {
               _id: 1,
              resId: '$_id.resId',
              attachment: '$_id.attachment',
              date: '$_id.date',
                "hoursCount" :
                        {
                            $switch:
                            {
                                branches: [
                                {
                                    case: {'$eq':['$_id.date',new Date('2018-01-01')]},
                                    then: 696
                                },
                                {
                                    case: {'$eq':['$_id.date',new Date('2018-05-01')]},
                                    then: 720
                                },
                                {
                                    case: {'$eq':['$_id.date',new Date('2017-06-01')]},
                                    then: 696
                                }
                                ],
                                default: '$_id.date'
                            }
                        },
        }
    },
```

Comment: Ok ,but that's not what I want ... I need to group my documents by month, not by day. Anyway, I've found the solution by my own. I'll be posting the solution here in a few minutes